# Why git filter-branch show "fatal: Needed a single revision" error?

Tags: git, github

I want to remove sensitive data from my repository. according to the [github's help page](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/) I use this command:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch projectname-firebase-crashreporting-00000-q12345fg45.json'
```

to remove **projectname-firebase-crashreporting-00000-q12345fg45.json** file from all my commits but I encounter this error:

> fatal: Needed a single revision

I use this git command for 2 other files and it works well but I don't know why I get this error now.I searched it, I just found some tips for rebase command.

What should I do?

Comment: I think your remote and local HEAD are not in sync, before you issue your command try to `git pull` and they try.

Comment: For me it has happened when the HEAD has had a reference, but a reference (file) has not existed.